# Comparing elements from different columns but from the same data frame with R

Tags: r, dataframe, compare

I am trying to determine sequence similarity.
I would like to create a function to compare `df` elements, for the following example:

```
   V1  V2 V3  V4
1  C   D  A   D  
2  A   A  S   E 
3  V   T  T   V
4  A   T  S   S 
5  C   D  R   Y 
6  C   A  D   V
7  V   T  E   T 
8  A   T  A   A
9  R   V  V   W
10 W   R  D   D
```

I want to compare the first element from the first column with a first element from the second column. If it matches == 1, else 0. Then the second element from the first column compared with the second element from the second column. and so on.

For example:

```
C != D -----0
A == A -----1
```

That way I would like to compare column 1 with column 2 then column 3 and column 4.
Then column 2 compare with column 3 and column 4.
Then column 3 with column 4.

The output would be just the numbers:

```
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
compared_df <- ifelse(df_trial$V1==df_trial$V2,1,ifelse(df_trial$V1==df_trial$V2,0,NA))
compared_df
```

As suggested, I tried the following:

```
compared_df1 <- df_trial$matches <- as.integer(df_trial$V1 == df_trial$V2)
```

This works well for small sample comparison. Is there a way to compare more globally? Like for the updated columns.

Comment: That would be `df$matches <- as.integer(df$V1 == df$V2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ronak Shah said in the comment using the following is sufficent in the case you want to compare 2 values:

```
df$matches <- as.integer(df$V1 == df$V2)
```

Another option which is applicable to more the 2 rows as well is to use `apply` to check for the number of unique elements in a row in the following way:

```
df$matches = apply(df, 1, function(x) as.integer(length(unique(x)) == 1))
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. The first one works well for the comparison of a small sample. For the second option with 'apply', I am trying to determine only if they match or not. Would 'apply()' still be suitable for that?

Comment: @student24 yes, of course depend on what you wish to achieve. But both ways gives the same results its only that the second option will be good for the case where you want to compare more then 2 columns